# MIPS - Round Number

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am trying to develop the execution of a simple program in MIPS, but I am breaking my head on a topic. How do I get the system to return or show me a rounded number?

**EXAMPLE**

I enter a data number equal to `1.876542` and I want the system to show me the following:

```
The rounded number is: 1.88
```

**CODE**

```
*.data
txt1: .asciiz "Enter number: "
txt2: .asciiz "The rounded number is: "
  
.text
li $v0, 4
la $a0, txt1
syscall
li $v0, 6
syscall
movf.s $f1, $f0
.globl begin
begin
jal print_roundnumber
j exit
    
print_roundnumber:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, txt2
syscall
movf.s $f12, $f1
li $v0, 2   
syscall     
jr $ra      
exit:
li $v0, 10 
syscall
```

Comment: The trivial way would be to multiply your number by the appropriate power of 10 to get the precision required (e.g. by 100). Convert to integer, subtract from the scaled number to get the remaining digits. Compare to 0.5 to see if you need to round up, add one if so. Print the result scaled back using integer arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me how it would look in the code?

Comment: It's just basic arithmetic, which part is causing you problem? Surely you can add, subtract and multiply?

Comment: @Jester, even easier is: multiply by power of ten, add 0.5, then truncate to integer.

Comment: Yeah that is simpler :)

Comment: Thank U. Understand now.

Comment: I added these lines. 

li $t5, x
mtc1 $t5, $f5
cvt.s.w $f5,$f5
mul.s $f12,$f12,$f5
trunc.w.s $f12,$f12
cvt.s.w $f12,$f12
div.s $f12,$f12,$f5  

When I run, for example, 9.9876, the system shows 9.98. And when I put 1,231, it shows 1.23. In the first case it should be 9.99. You are not rounding the number. How do I solve this part?

Comment: As prl said, you should add 0.5 before truncation.